# What is sharing on my mac

Tags: mac

In my finder window of the OS X 10.9.1 mac software version installed on a new desktop mac, I frequently see something else connected as shared but will not allow me to get the info and I do not know what it is?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would be helpful

Comment: Are you asking what Sharing is and how it works, how do identify who is using Sharing to access your computer remotely or are you refering to the Sharing part in the left pane of a Finder window? Please clarify (and add a screenshot if possible), we'll put the question on hold for now to prevent people from proving answers based on guesses.

Comment: how do identify who is using Sharing to access your computer remotely

Comment: Edit such clarifications into your question rather than in a comment so they are part of the question.